# Plastic in Docker windows containers

Tags: windows, powershell, dockerfile, plasticscm

I want to use plastic SCM in Docker windows containers.
I searched in Plastic and found Linux containers docker file
SO I want to try my own docker file for that I need to know the command to download the SCM installation file using PowerShell and install it without the GUI (arguments to pass for installation) via Powershell

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I'm currently using for my windows image. I will warn you that it does take ~5-10 minutes to install during the build process, but everything works great besides that. It works pretty simply, it creates a temp folder and uses the URL for the download to download the installer there, then runs the installer, and finally deletes the temp folder.

```
    #This installs plastic

    $tempFolder = "C:\Temp"
    $plasticURL = "https://www.plasticscm.com/download/downloadinstaller/10.0.16.5882/plasticscm/windows/client"
    $installerName = "plasticinstalling.exe"

    New-Item $tempFolder -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null

    $installerLocation = (Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath $installerName -ErrorAction Stop)

    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $plasticURL -OutFile $installerLocation -ErrorAction Stop

    Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerLocation -ArgumentList "--mode","unattended" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru

    Remove-Item -Recurse $tempFolder -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Then, in my docker file I just call the script:

```
    RUN powershell -Command C:\Scripts\installPlastic.ps1
```

Hope this helped and feel free to reach out with more questions.